# Adjacency Matrix with Letters as Index

Tags: java, matrix, adjacency-matrix, digraphs

Hi I'm looking for a way to implement an adjaceny matrix, where I can use letters as the index... something like a hashmap?

I currently use a simple 2D array and I have converted the letters A-Z into indices 0-25 (I could convert back afterward but this seems like unncessary coding) such that:

```
matrix[initial][final] = 1;
```

Which gives:

```
Index 0    1    2    3
   0  0    1    1    0

   1  1    0    0    0

   2  0    1    0    0

   3  0    1    1    0
```

I would like to be able to directly implement this using A, B, C, D instead of 0, 1, 2, 3.

For example if I wanted to add an entry:

```
matrix['A']['B'] = 1
```

(Please note that this should run on jdk 8)

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Try this code maybe helpful.
Idea is that data is stored on 2D array, but in order to access the elements, special methods where created.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Mat {

    int arr[][];
    Map<String,Integer> hm;
    int counter=0;
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Mat m = new Mat();
        //create elements
        m.addElement("a", "b", 2);
        m.addElement("b", "a", 3);
        m.addElement("c", "b", 33);
        //get a particular element
        System.out.println("[c,b]="+m.getElement("c", "b"));
        //iterate through 2Dmatrix
        for(int i=0;i<m.arr.length;i++)
            for(int j=0; j<m.arr[i].length;j++)
            {
                System.out.println("["+m.getArr(i, j)[0]+","+m.getArr(i, j)[1]+"]="+m.arr[i][j]+" ("+m.getElement(m.getArr(i, j)[0], m.getArr(i, j)[1])+")");
            }

    }
    //initialize here what ever letters are used, can be also numbers but in string format
    Mat()
    {
        hm = new HashMap<String,Integer>();;
        hm.put("a",counter++);
        hm.put("b",counter++);
        hm.put("c",counter++);
        arr = new int[hm.size()][hm.size()];
    }

    public int getElement(String e1, String e2)
    {
        int i=hm.get(e1);
        int j=hm.get(e2);
        return arr[i][j];
    }

    public void addElement(String e1,String e2, int value)
    {
        int i=hm.get(e1);
        int j=hm.get(e2);
        arr[i][j] = value;
    }

    public String [] getArr(int i, int j)
    {
        String s[] = new String[2];
        for(String str: hm.keySet())
        {
            if(hm.get(str) == i)
            {
                s[0] = str;
            };
            if(hm.get(str) == j)
            {
                s[1] = str;
            };
        }
        return s;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[c,b]=33

//same values obtaining with two methods either directly form array
// or using a special one

[a,a]=0 (0)
[a,b]=2 (2)
[a,c]=0 (0)
[b,a]=3 (3)
[b,b]=0 (0)
[b,c]=0 (0)
[c,a]=0 (0)
[c,b]=33 (33)
[c,c]=0 (0)
```